# WebView component not show web page: Webpage not available

Tags: android, android-webview

Android Studio 3.2.

In my Manifiest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In my xml layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aboutUsToolBar" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In my activity:

```
   private void init(String webUrl) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "init: load_url_in_web_view : " + webUrl);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolBar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
    }

    // open external web page inside WebView component
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            view.loadUrl(webUrl);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And here result on Android 4.4:

[image]
On Android 6.0+ page `webUrl` success open.

If I use url "http://www.google.com" then it open success.
Also if I open `webUrl` in web browser it success open.

Comment: Hello did you find any solution ?? i have this problem in some web pages in android 4.2

Answer (score 0):

> add INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

> Main.xml

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

> Activity.java

```
private String postUrl = “https://www.google.com”;
 private WebView webView;

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(postUrl);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```